# Merge two almost identical rows in a csv.DictReader in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I have the following data and just can't think of a solution to merge this in Python:

Data looks like this:

```
ID    OFFSET    TEXT
1     1         This text is short
2     1         This text is super long and got cut by the database s
2     2000      o it will come out like this
3     1         I'm short too
```

I've been trying to use csv.DictReader and csv.DictWriter.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code only then we will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

use `itertools.groupby` to group by id, then join the texts:

```
import itertools
import operator

#dr is the DictRreader
for dbid, rows in itertools.groupby(dr, key=operator.itemgetter('ID')):
    print(dbid, ''.join(row['TEXT'] for row in rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

the groupby will create tuples where the tuple values is a list of TEXT item by ID.

```
txt="""ID,OFFSET,TEXT
1,     1,         This text is short
2,     1,         This text is super long and got cut by the database s
2,     2000,      o it will come out like this
3,     1,         I'm short too
"""

from io import StringIO
f = StringIO(txt)
df = pd.read_table(f,sep =',')

df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)


for my_tuple in df.groupby(df.index)['TEXT']:
    lst=[item.strip() for item in my_tuple[1]]
    print(". ".join(lst))
    print("\n")
```

output:

```
This text is short

This text is super long and got cut by the database s. o it will come out like this

 I'm short too
```

Answer (score -1):

The classes `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` are for CSV files and although you can probably make them read fixed column-delineated files like the one you show, it isn't really necessary and can complicate things.

Assuming the records are in order, all you need to do is:

- read each line (throwing away the first)
- read the ID, offset and text (throwing away the offset)
- if the ID is new, store a mapping from ID to text
- if the ID is not new, append the text.

Python can do all this without modules.

Here's an initial approach:

```
text="""
ID    OFFSET    TEXT
1     1         This text is short
2     1         This text is super long and got cut by the database s
2     2000      o it will come out like this
3     1         I'm short too
""".strip()

lines = text.splitlines()
columns = lines.pop(0)  # don't need the columns
result = dict()

for line in lines:
    # the maxsplit arg is important to keep all the text
    id, offset, text = line.split(maxsplit=2)
    if id in result:
        result[id] += text
    else:
        result[id] = text

print("Result:")
for id, text in result.items():
    print(f"ID {id} -> '{text}'")
```

This uses Python 3.6 f-strings, but you can get the same results without that if you prefer, e.g.:

```
...
    print("ID %s -> '%s'" % (id, text)
```

Either way, the result is:

```
Result:
ID 1 -> 'This text is short'
ID 2 -> 'This text is super long and got cut by the database so it will come out like this'
ID 3 -> 'I'm short too'
```

The conditional check `if id in result` is "ok" but you can avoid it using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(str)
for line in lines:
    id, offset, text = line.split(maxsplit=2)
    result[id] += text  # <-- much better

print("Result:")
for id, text in result.items():
    print(f"ID {id} -> '{text}'")
```

The `collections` package has a number of handy utilities like that.